# C8051F340 flash reading always 255

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051

I am using C8051F340 and save some random number to my its flash, the problems that I have right now is if I erase first and write then read it, the value is right. But if I just use the read function, it only give me 255 inside the correct value.
Here is the code.

```
buf[0] = 1;
buf[1] = 1;
buf[2] = 1;
buf[3] = 1;
buf[4] = 1;
buf[5] = 0;
buf[6] = 1;
buf[7] = 1;
buf[8] = 1;
buf[9] = 1;
buf[10] = 1;
buf[11] = 1;
buf[12] = 1;
buf[13] = 1;
buf[14] = 1;
buf[15] = 1;


FLASH_PageErase (0x3200);
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
FLASH_ByteWrite(0x3200+i, buf[i]);
read_buf[i] = FLASH_ByteRead (0x3200+i);
}
```

after those code, I can find my read_buf[i] is : 1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

But if I only do read function:

```
buf[0] = 1;
buf[1] = 1;
buf[2] = 1;
buf[3] = 1;
buf[4] = 1;
buf[5] = 0;
buf[6] = 1;
buf[7] = 1;
buf[8] = 1;
buf[9] = 1;
buf[10] = 1;
buf[11] = 1;
buf[12] = 1;
buf[13] = 1;
buf[14] = 1;
buf[15] = 1;


for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{

read_buf[i] = FLASH_ByteRead (0x3200+i);
}
```

the result of my read_buf[i] is : 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but you do realize that erasing flash memory sets all the bits to 1 and programming flash is about setting some of the bits to 0? So reading after erasing should yield just what you got.

Comment: Are you sure your flash at address 0x3200 is not empty? Usually empty flash is written with 0xFF and that's what you are getting back